# Passing $_GET variable using mod_rewrite / Smarty

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, get, smarty

I'm having difficulty trying to pass over the $_GET variable (event) which is the event_id. The website is built with PHP and Smarty template engine and mod_rewrite works fine.

Working link/Querystring:

**/event.php?event=2**

Rewrite:

**/events/2**

htacces:

**RewriteRule ^/events/?$ /event.php?event=$1 [QSA]**

When viewing the page **/events/2** it is looking for the template *2.inc.html* but *event.php* is already specifying the template as *event.inc.html* which should display the event details from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess, the leading prefix (incl trailing slash of the prefix) is stripped off before you compare, so ^/events can never match.  Try dropping the first / in the RewriteRule.

Also drop the first $, the input here (rewritelog would show you) is /events/2 so there is never a match for events/?$. Maybe you meant ^events/(\d+) so you can actually use the substitution of event=$1.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've changed it to **RewriteRule   ^events/?$   event.php?event=$1 [QSA]** however it's still looking for 1.inc.html

Comment: Also drop the first $, the input here  (rewritelog would show you) is /events/2 so there is never a match for events/?$. Maybe you meant ^events/(\d+) so you can actually use the substitution of event=$1.

Comment: Updated to **RewriteRule   ^events/(\d+)  event.php?event=$1 [QSA]** is that right? but still looking for template 2.inc.html (sorry I typed 1 by mistake previously)... *Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "2.inc.html" in...*

Comment: any further suggestions?